# FirebaseDatabase Query : How to query some data basing on some values from other childs. For FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm working on my app that has a fragment, this fragment displays new users with a follow button using this query :

```
query = mDatabaseref.child("users").orderByChild("date").limitToLast(10);
```

After a follow button is clicked, the current `User Uid` gets saved as a child in the other child that has a name "Follows" with 2 other child's "following" and "followers" as it showed in the below picture :

[image]

what I want to do is to make a `Query` for an other fragment with the name **Following** and show all the users that the **Current** user is following with the ability of getting their names, I was thinking of making a data `dataSnapshot` in the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` `onBindViewHolder` method basing on the `Uid` tooken from the childs, but I think it's gonna be complex, on the other hand, i tried to sort the follows in the user Info child direclty, but it leads to a strange behaviour on the `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to write you all the code including your `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`, I will show you just how to query to get the desired results. As i understand, here is the problem. So in order to achieve this, you need to query your database twice, once to get all those ids and second, based on those ids to get the names. So, please use the following code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference followingRef = rootRef.child("follows").child(uid).child("following");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String userId = ds.getKey();

            DatabaseReference userIdRef = rootRef.child("users").child(userId);
            ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String name = dSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                        Log.d("TAG", name);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            };
            userIdRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
followingRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The result in your logcat will be all the names of the followers that belong to a single user.

Comment: What i want to do is to implement all the users to the recycler using these ids , at the same time i want to set the informations of each user to his item. (Username and some info like city)
How would i achieve that using your code. Thank u ❤
Don't u think i should use an **valueEventListener** inside the the **onBindViewHolder** using the id from the modelObject to retrieve those info and set them to the view holder items?

Comment: Yes, this what this code does. I just gave you a simple example for logging the `name`, but in the same way you can do it for the other fields. Please try the code above. Does this code print the desired result, the names of the followers that belong to a single user?

Comment: Yes it prints them, but i guess Im gonna use a more simple way, im gonna create an ObjectClass with userUid, City, and name. And use it as an object class for the adapter. And as a class for the snapshot to save these data when you follow someone. What do u think?

Comment: Grad to hear that it worked. There is no simply way. To get the combined data, you need to query your database twice. You cannot query using only a single query. There is no way for doing that. Regarding a model class, yes  you can do it. If you want the simplest approach, you can use the code above that uses only `String` class. Cheers!